# MVC DropDownList from database

Tags: database, drop-down-menu

I am new in c# and MVC and this is my question:

For my new website, I would like to have a DropDownList in my header so the visitors can choose a Currency.

I have a SQL server table named CurrencyList

I have a Controller named BaseController : Controller

I have a model:

```
public partial class CurrencyList 
{
public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> CurrencyValue { get; set; }
public string Currency { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, how do I get the datas in the select? And how do I manage the Post?
For my select, I will use only the field Currency, and by default EUR will be selected.

Onchange, I would like to save the Currency value in a session and/or cookie.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax Get method to call the method of controller which get data for bind dropdown list

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Patel. Can I have some more details/examples. As I said I'm new (very new ;-))

Comment: please refer this link http://tutorial.techaltum.com/dropdown-binding-using-ajax-in-mvc.html

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Patel. Any suggestion without json?